# Enabling Shortcut Keys in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I am new to Git Project Configuration in Eclipse. Before This I was working with a Project Check out from SVN. That Time i could use some shortcut keys. Like If i m using like object obj. means it shows all the methods in the corresponding class.

But after moving to Git Project if i am using obj. it shows a message in a box like "**The compilation unit is not on the buid path of java project**". Particularly I am using the Java EE Perspective.

Comment: Looks like your class is not in a folder where eclipse expect java class files.

Answer (score 1):

- Are you sure you not opening class from [derived](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/resAdv_derived.htm) folder? It may be kind of a generated class.
- When doing a checkout (clone, in git) have you checked a project type in one of the steps? [image].

Most likely IDE specific files are not under version control, so you need to configure it manually.

- If not, do additional project reconfiguration - add [project facets](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.doc.user/topics/cfacets.html).
- Or just manually configure project build path to contain these directories as source directories.